# Page_Load method running twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a VS 2013 project using built-in asp.net Web Application Web Forms template. By putting a breakpoint in the Page_Load method of a page I can see the method is executed twice between pressing F5 and the page appearing. Why? And can I / should I stop this behaviour?

Apologies for not providing enough detail. The code is completely vanilla, untouched template code generated by VS Exp 2013 for Web.

The ASPX file is

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="mycompanyname.B1WebApp.About" %>
```

The ~/Site.Master has an empty Page_Load method (not sure this is relevant)

The code behind is

```
public partial class About : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean Nothing;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm - Page_load should only be called once per page life cycle unless you call it explicit yourself. However if it is a user control or similar, you might be using it multiple times on your master page/parent page?

Comment: the only possible way to rectify this issues is either you Delete the Page_load method and retype the page load method or Delete the page and create it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid pageload function working on each postbacks by `!IsPostBack`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }
```

A **User control** with this master page can also cause pageload execute twice...

Comment: Thanks for this. Very helpful. It would surely be helpful if a completely vanilla template project created by VS had this check in the Page_Load method as this must trip up everyone fresh to it who tries to get some code to run as the page loads. Or should I be putting my code that should run only once on page load somewhere else?

Comment: The code which has to be executed first can be put inside pageload..In cases when pageload again executes..ie,when a button click or any postbacks,!ispostback prevents the codelines in pageload executing again,Regards..

Answer (score 1):

This is part asp.net web forms, as a page posts back to itself whenever a server control is used on a page. It has been like this forever.

You need to do a check on page load:

```
if(!IsPostBack) 
{  
//Code for first time load 
}
 else 
{ 
// code whenever you have a postback
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Very easy when you know how. Which I didn't. Thanks for your help. What kind of code would you put in the else statement above? And could it be executed more than the twice I have observed?